# Changing a Select Query to a Count Distinct Query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using a Select query to select Members, a variable that serves as a unique identifier, and transaction date, a Date format (MM/DD/YYYY).

```
Select Members , transaction_date,
FROM table WHERE Criteria = 'xxx'
Group by Members, transaction_date;
```

My ultimate aim is to count the # of unique members by month (i.e., a unique member in day 3, 6, 12 of a month is only counted once).  I don't want to select any data, but rather run this calculation (count distinct by month) and output the calculation.

Comment: `mysql` or `postgres`?

Comment: postgres using SQL Workbench

Comment: If `Members` is a unique identifier, why are you bothering to aggregate anything with it?  Perhaps you should include sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give distinct count per month.

<kbd>**[`SQLFiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/81f08/4)**</kbd>

```
select month,count(*) as distinct_Count_month 
from
(
    select members,to_char(transaction_date, 'YYYY-MM') as month
    from table1
    /* add your where condition */
    group by members,to_char(transaction_date, 'YYYY-MM')
) a
group by month
```

So for this input

```
+---------+------------------+
| members | transaction_date |
+---------+------------------+
|       1 | 12/23/2015       |
|       1 | 11/23/2015       |
|       1 | 11/24/2015       |
|       2 | 11/24/2015       |
|       2 | 10/24/2015       |
+---------+------------------+
```

You will get this output

```
+----------+----------------------+
|  month   | distinct_count_month |
+----------+----------------------+
| 2015-10  |                    1 |
| 2015-11  |                    2 |
| 2015-12  |                    1 |
+----------+----------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this. This might work. 
SELECT  REPLACE(CONVERT(DATE,transaction_date,101),'-','/') AS [DATE], 
COUNT(MEMBERS) AS [NO OF MEMBERS]

FROM BAR

WHERE REPLACE(CONVERT(DATE,transaction_date,101),'-','/') IN 

    (

    SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(DATE,transaction_date,101),'-','/') 

    FROM BAR

    )

GROUP BY REPLACE(CONVERT(DATE,transaction_date,101),'-','/')

ORDER BY REPLACE(CONVERT(DATE,transaction_date,101),'-','/')

Answer (score 0):

Use COUNT(DISTINCT members) and date_trunc('month', transaction_date) to retain timestamps for most calculations (and this can also help with ordering the result). to_char() can then be used to control the display format but it isn't required elsewhere.

```
SELECT
      to_char(date_trunc('month', transaction_date), 'YYYY-MM')
    , COUNT(DISTINCT members) AS distinct_Count_month
FROM table1
GROUP BY
      date_trunc('month', transaction_date)
;
```

result sample:

```
| to_char | distinct_count_month |
|---------|----------------------|
| 2015-10 |                    1 |
| 2015-11 |                    2 |
| 2015-12 |                    1 |
```

see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/57294/2